# If-else statement in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which consist 90 Billion transaction records. The data frame looks like -

```
id          marital_status     age    new_class_desc      is_child          
1              Married          35    kids_sec                 0
2              Single           28    Other                    1
3              Married          32    Other                    1
5              Married          42    kids_sec                 0
2              Single           28    Other                    1
7              Single           27    kids_sec                 0
```

I want the data frame looks like -

```
id       marital_status     age     is_child   new_class_desc    new_is_child          
1           Married          35        0       kids_sec            1
2           Single           28        0       Other               0
3           Married          32        1       Other               1
5           Married          42        0       kids_sec            1
2           Single           28        1       Other               1
7           Single           27        0       kids_sec            0
```

I have done the code but data set is huge so every time kernel is dead

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def new_is_child(var1,var2,var3):

    if((var1 == 'Married') & (var2 == 'kids_sec') & (var3 >=33)):
        new_var =  1
    else:
        new_var = test_df['is_child']
    return new_var

test_df['new_is_child'] = test_df.apply(lambda row : new_is_child(row['marital_status'],row['new_class_desc'],row['age']), axis=1)
```

Any good way I can solve this problem??

Comment: You can try applying function on chunks of dataframe and concatenate at the end. If memory is constraint you can store the intermediate results in a csv and concatenate it using cat.

Comment: You can check performance timings in answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `df.where`, you can modify the data on a single condition. If it does match your condition, it'll modify the data with the parameter you wish to use, else, it'll leave the data untouched.

I think you should directly modify the data of `is_child` instead of creating a new column, since it'll return a new DataFrame, the original data will be untouched, but I guess it will depend of your use case.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
print(df)
#    id marital_status  age new_class_desc  is_child
# 0   1        Married   35       kids_sec         0
# 1   2         Single   28          Other         1
# 2   3        Married   32          Other         1
# 3   5        Married   42       kids_sec         0
# 4   2         Single   28          Other         1
# 5   7         Single   27       kids_sec         0

condition = ~((df['marital_status'] == 'Married') &\
            (df['new_class_desc'] == 'kids_sec') &\
            (df['age'] >= 33))

# Creating the new column, duping your original is_child.
df['new_col'] = df.loc[:, 'is_child']

# Applying your condition using df.where.
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.where(condition, 1)
print(df)
#    id marital_status  age new_class_desc  is_child  new_col
# 0   1        Married   35       kids_sec         0        1
# 1   2         Single   28          Other         1        1
# 2   3        Married   32          Other         1        1
# 3   5        Married   42       kids_sec         0        1
# 4   2         Single   28          Other         1        1
# 5   7         Single   27       kids_sec         0        0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with casting boolean mask to numpy array is fastest solution in large DataFrame:

```
m = (df['marital_status'].values == 'Married') & 
    (df['new_class_desc'].values == 'kids_sec') & 
    (df['age'].values >=33)

df['new_is_child'] = np.where(m, 1, df['is_child'])
print (df)
   id marital_status  age new_class_desc  is_child  new_is_child
0   1        Married   35       kids_sec         0             1
1   2         Single   28          Other         0             0
2   3        Married   32          Other         1             1
3   5        Married   42       kids_sec         0             1
4   2         Single   28          Other         1             1
5   7         Single   27       kids_sec         0             0
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'marital_status': np.random.choice(['Married','Single'], N),
                   'age':np.random.randint(20,80,N),
                   'new_class_desc':np.random.choice(['kids_sec','Other'], N),
                   'is_child':np.random.choice([0,1], N)})
```

---

```
In [301]: %%timeit
     ...: m = (df['marital_status'].values == 'Married') & (df['new_class_desc'].values == 'kids_sec') & (df['age'].values >=33)
     ...: df['new_is_child'] = np.where(m, 1, df['is_child'])
     ...: 
55.4 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [300]: %%timeit
     ...: cond = (df['marital_status'] == 'Married') & (df['new_class_desc'] == 'kids_sec') & (df['age'] >= 33)
     ...: df.loc[cond, 'new_is_child'] = 1
     ...: df['new_is_child'] = df['new_is_child'].fillna(df['is_child'])
     ...: 
148 ms ± 503 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [301]: %%timeit
     ...: condition = ~((df['marital_status'] == 'Married') &\
     ...:             (df['new_class_desc'] == 'kids_sec') &\
     ...:             (df['age'] >= 33))
     ...: 
     ...: df['new_col'] = df.loc[:, 'is_child']
     ...: 
     ...: df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.where(condition, 1)
     ...: 
926 ms ± 7.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Obviously, but you could show timings on 1 or 2 million, which will probably scale same to bigger amounts.

Comment: The benchmark looks good ! I was wondering the results between pandas and numpy but didn't have the time to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
cond = (test_df['marital_status'] == 'Married') & (
    test_df['new_class_desc'] == 'kids_sec') & (test_df['age'] >= 33)
test_df.loc[cond, 'new_is_child'] = 1
test_df['new_is_child'] = test_df['new_is_child'].fillna(test_df['is_child'])
```

Output:

```
  id marital_status  age new_class_desc is_child new_is_child
0  1        Married   35       kids_sec        0            1
1  2         Single   28          Other        1            1
2  3        Married   32          Other        1            1
3  5        Married   42       kids_sec        0            1
4  2         Single   28          Other        1            1
5  7         Single   27       kids_sec        0            0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where` method is what you need.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html

```
test_df['is_child'].where(~(test_df['marital_status'] == 'Married' & ...other conditions...), 1)
```

Note the negate in the front. `Series.where(cond, other)` returns the `series` value if `cond` is True, otherwise, the `other` value

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to read the csv in chunks and keep adding to a new df with schema as required. The code can be:

```
tempDF = pd.read_csv("data.csv",nrows=1)
cols = tempDF.columns.values.tolist()
newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv',chunksize=csize):
    chunk['new_is_child'] = chunk.apply(lambda row : new_is_child(row['marital_status'],row['new_class_desc'],row['age']), axis=1)
    newDF = pd.concat([newDF,chunk])
```

The point is to reduce the load on the kernel by modifying the file in chunks. Thus, finding the appropriate csize that is the chunk size is important in this case. Think this will work fine.